# Adding flutter Path to .zshrc causes error in iTerm with oh-my-zsh

Tags: linux, terminal, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I am going to add Path of `flutter` to `.zshrc` permanently.

when I installed either iTerm or oh-my-sh, it rewritten .zshrc file. Now if I add `export PATH=$HOME/coding/flutter/env/flutter/bin` and enter `source ./.zshrc` on iTerm, I am getting the following errors.

```
/Users/mine/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:56: command not found: mkdir
/Users/mine/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:117: command not found: rm
zrecompile:99: command not found: wc
zrecompile:135: command not found: mv
detect-clipboard:33: command not found: uname
nvm:7: command not found: tr
nvm:7: command not found: tr
```

How can I add other path to `.zshrc` ?

If I add the path, I can run `flutter` on terminal but many other commands are not found.
I tried to add the `export` to `.zprofile` or some other files but still the same error.

Comment: Remove what you've just typed in `.zshrc` and others. I think you overwrote the entire PATH. Try this. `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/coding/flutter/env/flutter/bin`

Comment: It worked very well. Thank you! Can you tell me what is the difference between my command and yours?

Comment: let's say, A='apple'. if you assign A='banana', A is 'banana' now. but If you call the A (apple) before assign banana, you can hold both. `A=$A:banana`. In this case, A will show `apple:banana`.  this is what you need. You needed to hold both. but what you did is `A=banana`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say, `A='apple'`.
if you assign `A='banana'`, A is 'banana' now.

But If you expand the `A` (which has `apple`) before assign `banana`, `A` would hold both. It would be `A=$A:banana`.

In this case, `A` will `apple:banana`. this is what you need.

You needed to hold both. But what you did is `A=banana`

**I suggest putting this line below in your `.zshrc`.**

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/coding/flutter/env/flutter/bin
```

The line will expand the current `$PATH`, which doesn't have the flutter PATH, before assigning `$HOME/coding/flutter/env/flutter/bin`.